# How to get modified data from a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a **`RecyclerView`** to show a list of filters passed with the adapter. This list has items with a Boolean to check if the item was pressed or not. I need to get this data back to the activity to have a list of checked elements. How I can achieve this?

***RecyclerView Adapter***

```
public class RvFilterAdapter extends BaseQuickAdapter<FilterSelectable, BaseViewHolder> {

    public RvFilterAdapter(int layoutResId, List data) {
        super(R.layout.filter_item, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void convert(BaseViewHolder viewHolder, FilterSelectable item) {

        int position = viewHolder.getLayoutPosition();

        setupViews(viewHolder, item);
        setupListeners(viewHolder, item);

        Log.e("RV", "position=" + position + " i=" + item.getId() +" name=" + item.getName() + " checked=" + item.isSelected());

    }

    public void setupViews(BaseViewHolder baseViewHolder, FilterSelectable item){

        baseViewHolder
                .setText(R.id.tv_filter_name, item.getName())
                .setChecked(R.id.tbc_filter, item.isSelected())
                .addOnClickListener(R.id.ll_filter_root)
                .addOnClickListener(R.id.tbc_filter);

    }

    public void setupListeners(BaseViewHolder baseViewHolder, final FilterSelectable item){

        baseViewHolder.getView(R.id.tbc_filter).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v.isSelected()){
                    v.setSelected(false);
                    item.setSelected(false);
                }else{
                    v.setSelected(true);
                    item.setSelected(true);
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

***FilterActivity***

```
RvFilterAdapter filterAdapter = new RvFilterAdapter(this, R.layout.filter_item, filterList);
filterAdapter.openLoadAnimation();
recyclerView.setAdapter(filterAdapter);
```

How can I modify the filterList that I've passed to the adapter to mantain changes between the activity and the RecyclerView?

Thank you

Comment: did you try `yourAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` ?

Comment: you should be able to get the items using list passed to the adapter `filterList`, if in the adapter you are modifying items, then `filterList` will access (updated) items too

Answer (score 1):

Add following method to your adapter and use it in your activity like `adapter.getSelection()`

```
public List<Item> getSelection() {

    List<Item> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Item item: list) {
        if(item.isSelected()) {
           selectedItems.add(item);
        }
    }
    return selectedItems;
}
```